# Git-init creating a visible directory when executable present

Tags: git

When using [`git-init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) to initialize a repository, it creates a hidden directory called `.git` - I got that far.

But when I tried using the command on a directory which also contained the executable file that I had compiled from the source in that directory, it created a second, visible directory, called simply `git`, which contained several hundred files.

What is this directory, and what does it do?

I am using Linux Mint with bash.

Comment: What is creating the "git" directory? Please clarify your steps from an empty directory.

Comment: When he executes `git-init`.

Answer (score 0):

The .git directory contains the internal database of git, e.g., index, logs, etc.

The git commands only use the *.git* directory to store changes. If you like to learn more about using *git* check, e.g., https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Your mentioned *git* directory isn't used by git as default.

Answer (score 0):

From [git-ready.com](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html):

> One of the things I like best about Git is that it keeps all of its information in one place: your .git directory in your project’s root.

[This tutorial](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/git/) could also be helpful, as it tells you:

> The whole repository content is stored in a folder named .git in the root of the project folder: